# Node content links block for creating content not showing up for certain roles

Tags: nodes, users, organic-groups, entities

I'm having an issue with the "node content links" block I created to contain my node content links -- i.e., links that allow a user to create content -- not showing up for the users it's supposed to show up for. I've done a lot of research on this and still can't figure out what's going on. I'm using the Entityreference Prepopulate module in conjunction with Organic Groups to create a link that users can click on to create artcles that are then posted within the appropriate group.

It works perfectly for the admin role, but when I give authenticated users permission to create content, the block doesn't show up for them. I've made sure in the manage fields screen of the relevant content type (i.e., "Group Content") that everything looks OK (Groups Audience has an Entity Reference field type, the widget is "OG Reference", and I'm pretty sure the settings on each are sound, though I may have done something wrong so I'd be grateful if someone could tell me about any commonly made mistakes during this configuration step).

In the Permissions area (both the regular permissions and the permissions set aside for organic groups) everything looks fine, i.e., both the admin role and authenticated user role can create Group Content content as well as Group content, etc.

Then, on the block configuration page under "Roles," I've check-marked "authenticated user" and "administrator."

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did the "node content links" come from the OG Extras module?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?